# Check if first n bits of a number equal one in C

Tags: c

I want to check if the first n bits of a unsigned integer number are respectively 1 in C. Is there a better way than just iterating over the bits and checking each at a time?

See my (brute force) solution below:

```
bool areFirstBitsTrue(uint32_t number, uint8_t bits)
{
    uint8_t i;
    if(bits > sizeof(number))
    {
        bits = sizeof(number);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < bits; ++i)
    {
        if(! ( (number>>i) & 1) )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `return number & ((1u << bits) - 1) == (1u << bits) - 1;` (also note that you probably just want `int bits` or `unsigned bits`, `uint8_t` looks like a misguided optimization)

Comment: I think there's some duplicates of that question.

Comment: `if (number & mask) == mask` where mask is set to be the bits you're interested in.

Comment: Thank you for the comments.
Sorry for the duplication. I did not find the questions by searching in my terms.

Comment: Note `sizeof` is not - at all - the same as # of bits as you seem to assume in your example code. `sizeof (uint32_t)` should be 4, # of bits is 32, though.